# Make an exception at certain fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have a method that saves an author with the `.findOneAndUpdate`

`AuthorInterface` looks like this:

```js
    export interface AuthorInterface {
        name: string,
        bio: string,
        githubLink: string,
        stackoverflowLink: string,
        twitterLink: string,
        image: string,
        image_webp: string,
    }
```

In this case I need to make an exception here. `image` and `image_webp` are image paths and therefore I cannot just override the values. I already used `Omit` to remove it out of the `AuthorInterface` argument.

However typescript still complains at `author: { ...author }` that `image_webp` and `image` fields are missing. How do I tell typescript that I don't expect `image` and `image_webp` properties to be in the argument object?

```js
    public saveAuthor(_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId | string, author: Omit<AuthorInterface, "image" | "image_webp">): Promise<UserModelInterface | null> {
        return User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, { author: { ...author } }, { new: true }).exec()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

change your `AuthorInterface` like this

```js
export interface AuthorInterface {
    name: string,
    bio: string,
    githubLink: string,
    stackoverflowLink: string,
    twitterLink: string,
    image?: string,
    image_webp?: string,
}
```

Comment: i could but i actually use AuthorInterface on other places aswell. so i does not want to set it simply on optional

Comment: @Ifaruki As you don't want to change `AuthorInterface`, why not just set `image` or `image_webp` to `' '` when you don't want those properties instead of remove them from object ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the beauty of typescript.

```
public saveAuthor(_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId | string, author: unknown): Promise<UserModelInterface | null> {
    return User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, { author: author as AuthorInterface }, { new: true }).exec()
}
```

Comment: The beauty of _disabling_ typescript

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

interface AuthorInterface {
        name: string,
        bio: string,
        githubLink: string,
        stackoverflowLink: string,
        twitterLink: string,
        image: string,
        image_webp: string,
}

type AuthorUpdate = Omit<AuthorInterface, "image" | "image_webp">;

/**
 * I'd willing to bet, that you can change/update/modify
 * User object/class
 * 
 * Here what you should do:
 */
interface User {
        findOneAndUpdate: <T>(arg1: any, author: AuthorUpdate extends T ? AuthorUpdate : T, arg3: any) => any
}

/**
 * User mock, just for test purpose
 */
const User: User = {
        findOneAndUpdate: (...args: any[]) => { }
}

/**
 * Now, if you pass AuthorUpdate to findOneAndUpdate it should work as expected
 */
function saveAuthor(_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId | string, author: AuthorUpdate) {
        return User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, { author: { ...author } }, { new: true }).exec()
}

/**
 * If you have problems with my solution, please share the minimum reproducable example
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

For your `saveAuthor` function, the function only uses `author` to clone and pass to `User.findOneAndUpdate`.

To be very literal, you could type `saveAuthor`'s parameter as:

```
author: Parameters<(typeof User)['findOneAndUpdate']>[1].author
```

This is an ugly way of saying: "this function expects what `User.findOneAndUpdate` expects".

But a better way is to use the established type. Assuming `findOneAndUpdate` accepts `AuthorInterface` in the 2nd param for the author prop, just write:

```
author: AuthorInterface
```

But you're trying to remove properties.. This statement of yours sounds odd:

> "`image` and `image_webp` are image paths and therefore I cannot just override the values".

But ***you're not*** modifying these properties in `saveAuthor`. Are you worried about `User.findOneAndUpdate` modifying the properties? That should not matter since you're cloning the object with the spread operator: `{ ...author }`.

It sounds like you might be confusing types with values. Using `Omit` doesn't remove properties from the actual value; it only ***relaxes*** the parameter's type requirements. You can still pass in an object with `image` and `image_webp` in most cases (typescript's "excess property checks" heuristic will not kick in unless you're writing a *literal* object).

You seem to misunderstand the typescript error at `author: { ...author }`. You say  "How do I tell typescript that I don't expect these properties to be in this object?" But the error isn't about what your `saveAuthor` function expects, it's about what `User.findOneAndUpdate` expects. You've passed it a *deficient* `AuthorInterface` (not a full `AuthorInterface`), but it requires a *full* `AuthorInterface`.

If `User.findOneAndUpdate` is requiring too much, then you can change it to relax its parameter types. If you're trying to remove the values, do this:

```
author: {
    ...author,
    image: undefined,
    image_webp: undefined,
}
```

If `User.findOneAndUpdate`'s types don't accept this, then fix them by using nancy's answer, assuming the code supports this optionality.